# joining coordinates

Tags: matlab, gis

I have two sets of coordinates

```
lat1 is 144.9216
lat2 is 151.0393
long1 is -37.7784
long2 is -33.8131
```

These are the coordinates for Melbourne and Sydney. I want these two sets of points to be connected using a line but am having a lot of trouble.

Here is what i came up with

```
worldmap('Australia')
plotm([lat1,long2],[lat1,long2],'.')
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

when using

```
plotm([lat1,long2],[lat1,long2],'.')
```

you are specifying that you want a dot, simply use

```
plotm([lat1,long1],[lat2,long2])
```

and it will plot a line.

Comment: Double check the values you pass in as well, you're passing it [lat1,long2] twice which I imagine would just make a dot at that location.